# How to fire code in case of a success or failed form validation with jQuery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-events

It seems that jQuery validate plugin does not come with out of the box, success and failed callback options. How do I manage to launch some custom code when a form's validation fails?

We need to change certain layout elements not related to the fields itself when a player enters invalid data.

Hope it is still possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These options are included, just not as intuitively named as possible, they're [`submitHandler` and `invalidHandler`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
    //this runs when the form is invalid, not submitted
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    //this runs when the form is is valid
  }
});
```

Comment: oh dear, if that's correct i feel ashamed for my question :) i'm on it right now, will probably work just as i expect it to now :) thanks